# Sources of Error for Lab

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, rotational-kinematics, error-analysis

I am in AP Physics 1 and we did a lab where we compared a disc rolling down a ramp to a hoop rolling down a ramp. I have completed the lab, but my teacher wants us to come up with 5 sources of error, and solutions to those errors.

This is what I have come up with so far

- We used a ruler to measure the height of the ramp, and we might have measured it at an angle (Parallax)

  - Measure length of ramp and angle of ramp and use those two values to calculate height
- Reaction time

  - Record video of the disc/hoop rolling down ramp to get exact time
- Radius of disc/hoop measured with ruler (Low Precision)

  - Use digital caliper to get more accurate measurements

I need two more sources of error, but can't come up with anything

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Homework - so conceptually/in general try considering systematically for every measurement you made AND everything you used to measure
"what physical/environmental processes are they subject to?" and for each of those consider if it could alter the result of the measurement. Estimate the accuracy of each measurement you made, what was the basis for that estimate.

Comment: Repeat the experiment a lot of times and choose some suitable value based on square distance from mean and chi square test? Perhaps one could change the material of the ramp and/or hoop/disc? Perform the test using different discs/hoops from the same factory? Try not to do the experiment in a windy place :)? Redo it on the space station or in vacuum ;)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homework so I'll keep this conceptual.

In general try considering systematically for every measurement you made AND everything you used to measure "what physical/environmental processes are they subject to?" and for each of those consider if it could alter the result of the measurement.

Estimate the accuracy of each measurement you made, what was the basis for that estimate?

Answer (score 0):

We can only identify sources of error from the measurements you made, the methods you used and the calculations you made. You need to tell us in detail what you did.

On your errors so far :

- Did you measure the difference in height between the same 2 points, eg the point of contact? You could also use a plumb line to ensure you are measuring along the vertical line rather than at an angle.
- Replacing one measurement (height of ramp) with two measurements (length and angle of ramp) introduces more possibility of parallax errors. This will not reduce error. It is harder to measure an angle accurately than a distance : the ratio of 2 distances should be more accurate. The parallax error will be small, but the best ways of reducing it are to ensure that you eye is level with the reading and use a thin scale such as a steel tape-measure.
- Reaction time is probably the largest source of error. Using video is a good idea if it has an in-built timer. You could also use it to check if there is any **slipping** between the objects and the ramp.
- Using a digital caliper to measure diameter is good, but you need to do this at a few points along and around the cylinder, to get an average. Did you also measure the inner diameter of the hoop?

What other measurements did you make? Mass of disk and hoop? What instrument did you use? Did they have the same mass?

Did the disk and hoop roll down the ramp along the line of steepest descent, or at an angle? Did the hoop wobble?